# Acer Aspire One sometimes freezes on startup

Tags: 11.10, freeze, acer, ati

I have an Acer Aspire One with a dual core AMD 1GHZ processor and 2GB of ram.

I have Ubuntu 11.10 installed (full install, not wubi). I had this problem when I was using wubi, and I thought a full install would fix it but most of the time when I boot up ubuntu, after about 15 seconds on the desktop, it freezes, neither the mouse does not move  nor clicking does not work, key combinations don't work. I am a relative n00b to linux but is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! It sounds to me like you are experiencing some sort of X freeze. Can you take a look at this [Ubuntu Wiki article on diagnosing X freezes](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Troubleshooting/Freeze) if you have a spare computer you can use to help with debugging and [file a bug report](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug)? Thanks!

Comment: I am also experiencing the same issue. Any luck resolving it?

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Answer (score 0):

Try this: connect the Internet with wired cable first, then start your computer. If every thing is good, then the most probably problem is the Ethernet card and the wireless card share the same ID. If this is the case, you simply make PCI Lan disabled in BIOS.

Comment: Thanks, I don't have an issue with the internet, the entire system freezes on me. I cant do anything.

Comment: But, there is an issue with the Aspire One freezing when it tries to connect wirelessly to the Internet.  This may be the case as the machine boots and attempts to make a wireless connection automatically.  The advice to try a wired connection is sound as this will either confirm or eliminate this issue as a cause.  Should it be the problem, one fix is to disable the Ethernet controller and just use the wireless card.  See: http://linuxnorth.wordpress.com/2011/10/23/wireless-less/ for more information and detailed instructions on how to disable the Ethernet controller.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you might be experiencing a bug where Acer Aspire One's tend to freeze while trying to connect to a wireless network. A simple way to test it out (and to fix it if this is the problem) is to set "Network Boot" as the top priority in your BIOS's boot order. You can do this by pressing F2 to enter your BIOS settings. Navigate to the "Boot" setting and move "Network Boot" to a higher position than your hard drive (Preferably the top).

If the freezing still happens, you can undo this by moving network boot back to a lower priority.

Source: http://bernaerts.dyndns.org/linux/202-ubuntu-acer-ao722

Answer (score 0):

I was able to trace a similar problem to the `rtkit-daemon`, or perhaps
one of the processes that use it (the last entry in the syslog
always had `rtkit` in it).

After reading the man page for the rtkit-daemon, I tried adding
the line

```bash
RLIMIT_RTTIME=1
```

to the file

```bash
/usr/share/dbus_1/system_services/org.freedesktop.Realtime
```

Worked, to my great surprise. The 1 above was just an arbitrary guess.